# SCSS in vscode is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

this is the package.json and package-lock.json code

```js
//package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "scss": "^0.2.4"
  }
}
//package-lock.json
{
  "name": "PriceTable",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "dependencies": {
        "scss": "^0.2.4"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/ometa": {
      "version": "0.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ometa/-/ometa-0.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-9TxHNbptVq9aRrBN+3xDNMWW1E4=",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.2.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/scss": {
      "version": "0.2.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/scss/-/scss-0.2.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-BA2QPtN8XU+krTOuH9OJrBKk4GU=",
      "dependencies": {
        "ometa": "0.2.2"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.2.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ometa": {
      "version": "0.2.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ometa/-/ometa-0.2.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-9TxHNbptVq9aRrBN+3xDNMWW1E4="
    },
    "scss": {
      "version": "0.2.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/scss/-/scss-0.2.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-BA2QPtN8XU+krTOuH9OJrBKk4GU=",
      "requires": {
        "ometa": "0.2.2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to install Sass in vscode but when I click the run button on the left corner, it shows an error like this:

`"scss is not recognized as an internal or external command..."`

Please someone show me whats wrong
[image]

[scss is not recogized in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQMBZ.png)

Comment: what have you tried? can you share some code snippet? this is from vscode extension or npm script?

Comment: DId you install sass globally?

Comment: @kritiz i run cmd in powershell to install node and sass

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that Node is installed and functional.To test this, run the following command and see if it produces an output without errors.Basically, it should return the node and npm versions that are currently installed on your machine.

```
node -v //To check the installed node version
npm -v  //To check the installed npm version
```

After ensuring that node and npm are installed and working properly, I recommend that you install sass globally. This could be the case in this instance.

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

And then do

1. `npm i`, which in this case would be similar to `npm install --save-dev node-sass`
2. `npm run node-sass`

Then, run your script again and examine the results.

```
node-sass --styled expanded "*Your file path*"
```

Comment: when i run npm run node-sass it return error missing script: "node-sass". all the command you suggested above npm run node-sass work fine @dinindu

Comment: @LinhChys can you please share your package.json file as well with the question?

Comment: @dinidu i just edit my post please check